# History of deleted posts by community user

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, spam, offensive

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24508354/1275169) , I see an answer was deleted by user *community* (as it was most likely a spam). But the text, that replaced it, says I can look at revision history for details (I thought it's like when an edit was made to a post). But there doesn't seem to be any option to see anymore information.

Has something gone wrong and hence no history was available or simply the text is misleading that actually no history information was intended to be shown in the first place?

Here's picture for those can't see that post:

[image]

Comment: If the answer never was edited before being deleted, it makes sense for the link to revisions not to be present. You can build such a link yourself from the answer's id: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24508354/revisions. Presto! *Usefull content!*

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/1288) to "Remove links when a post is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags" for details.

Comment: So, in addition to replacing the posts content (if that is desirable), deleted posts should always show the revisions link...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for the hack :) I see that I had to insert "posts" there. Was it deliberately made available by SO or you just figured it out based on the experience of looking at revision history?

Comment: @BlueMoon, past experience (and it makes sense because the same route is used for the revisions of both questions and answers).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But if the intent was to *not* show spam content at all by SO, then this seems to be an unintentional side-effect of storing data in the same path/location, potentially a bug. But I don't know whether the was intention to hide it completely.

Comment: The text *revision history* **is a link**.

Comment: @Martijn, you have good eyes. `#444` versus `#888`at 0.7 opacity on that background basically makes the link invisible to me.

Comment: It's what we use to filter out the weak @FrédéricHamidi.

Comment: Todo: find bionic eyes.

Comment: I'm investigating ways to make this more obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've changed the style of the link to be more obvious.

[image]

This change will be live in the next production build (> `rev 2014.6.30.2351`).

Comment: No problem at all. The link was pretty invisible so this can only improve the situation.

Comment: How did it manage to receive 50 down votes before it got removed???

Comment: It was an engineered post on a local development build, not real.

Comment: By the way, I didn't noticed that you have replied to me until I ran into this post again, use comment replies, please.

Answer (score 4):

The text contains a link; *the revision history* leads directly to the post history view:

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24508354/revisions) for details.

On posts that have been edited, an additional *history* link appears next to the *share | edit | flag* links. You can use a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) that adds the link even for posts that have not been edited.

Comment: Any chance we could restyle that link so it does not require +100 on each eye to be visible?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I knew about the link because I noticed the mouse-over action before, not because I noticed a colour difference. An underline would indeed make it more visible.

Comment: I see (finally!). But it's not obvious that there's a link there (unless you hover over that text), especially when I am used to a visible difference between a *link* and plain text on SO with an explicit marker such as different color or underline etc.

Comment: @BlueMoon: I poked Oded on the original feature announcement to look at the styling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Hamidi used a different way to get to that link when it's actually *present* in the post itself!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi FWIW at Programmers, [link is clearly visible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nd7eq.png "example screen shot"). Given screen shots in the question I guess SO 10Kers better [complain to Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/165773 "he announced the feature implementation")